# How to write a parsec parser for a list of interspersed elements?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Let's say the input looks something like `foo#1 bar baz-3.qux [...]`. I want to write a parser that only consumes the input up until the first space before the `[`, which means `foo#1 bar baz-3.qux` (without the trailing space).

**How should I approach this using parsec?**

I can imagine something like

```
foo = many1 $ letter <|> digit <|> oneOf " #-."
```

but this consumes even the space at the end, which I'd like to avoid. What is a general approach to parsing a list of things interspersed with another thing? (Imagine it's not just  a space, but something that would also need to be parsed).

*P.S: I'm looking for the most general solution possible, not a clever hack that solves this particular example.*

Comment: [Do `sepBy` and `sepBy1` work?](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:sepBy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is exactly `notFollowedBy`. Something like

```
foo = many1 $     letter 
              <|> digit 
              <|> oneOf "#-." 
              <|> (try $ char ' ' >> notFollowedBy (char '[') >> return ' ')
```

You can abstract out the pattern to get the general function of course:

```
endedBy :: (Show y) => Parser x -> Parser x -> Parser y -> Parser [x]
endedBy p final terminal = many1 $ p <|> t where 
  t = try $ do
        x <- final
        notFollowedBy terminal
        return x

foo' = endedBy (letter <|> digit <|> oneOf "#-.") (char ' ') (char '[')
```